# When trying to use semantic ui I keep getting this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, popup, semantic-ui

Here is the the code. Below I have shown the js and html and when it runs I need to be able to click the "log in button" and open a semantic ui modal

```js
$('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="modaldiv" class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Profile Picture
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="description">
      <div class="ui header">We've auto-chosen a profile image for you.</div>
      <p>We've grabbed the following image from the <a href="https://www.gravatar.com" target="_blank">gravatar</a> image associated with your registered e-mail address.</p>
      <p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black button">
      Nope
    </div>
    <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
      Yep, that's me
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<a class="item" id="logIn">
  <i class="user icon"></i> Log In
</a>
```

I need it so that a semantic modal opens when i click login

Comment: `modal()` should be a `jQuery UI` method.  As far as I know, there is no `modal()` method in core jQuery.

Comment: Actually jQuery UI has `dialog()` where as Bootstrap has `modal()`.  Your source code doesn't appear to import either of these.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you have included the required scripts for [`jQuery Modal`](https://jquerymodal.com/).. (which I'm just guessing you're using..)

Adding the following to your HTML should fix this for you...

**Note**, that if you are not using `jQuery Modal` - you will need to include the appropriate scripts for the modal you are using...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

***Demo:***

```js
$("#btn").on('click', event => {
  $('#modaldiv').modal('show');
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div id="modaldiv" class="ui modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
      Profile Picture
    </div>
    <div class="content">

      <div class="description">
        <div class="ui header">We've auto-chosen a profile image for you.</div>
        <p>We've grabbed the following image from the <a href="https://www.gravatar.com" target="_blank">gravatar</a> image associated with your registered e-mail address.</p>
        <p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="ui black button">
        Nope
      </div>
      <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
        Yep, that's me
        <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<button id="btn">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: so i forgot to make the log in a button. how would i make it open a modal on click

Comment: Keep in mind questions effectively asking "how to use a plugin" are highly broad and should possibly ask for more focus, or closed as too broad.

Comment: I agree with @Taplar that your question is extremely broad.. it doesn't appear you have even tried anything to get the modal to open on click... With that being said, I updated my answer demonstrating how to accomplish this... [One of the many ways you can find in their documentation](https://jquerymodal.com/), which is a good place to look for examples of things like this.. I wanted to show you how to do this since you appear to be new to the site.. keep in mind most people will down vote you if you do not show any attempt at resolving your issue... Cheers.